# manipulate form variables before render()

Tags: forms, theming, views

I have the following line of code in a user-profile-form.tpl.php which Drupal uses to render an input field in the user's edit profile page.

```
print render($form['field_machine_name']);
// this field can be found in the database table field_data_field_machine_name
```

The issue is that I want to run the value field_machine_name through a function like `$form['field_machine_name'] = make_seo_url($form['field_machine_name'])` before I run the `render()` function.  But this totally breaks the form because `$form['field_machine_name']` is some very large array and `render()` output html input tag instead of the actual field_machine_name itself.

How does one actually go about massaging values in the `$form` variable before outputting it as an html field in `render()`?

Additionally, i want to make sure anytime field_machine_name is printed anywhere on the drupal site, i want it to run through the `make_seo_url()` function.  Is there a global place i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

The Form API has [#pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#pre_render) per element. You can use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to add your pre-render function to the list of functions that need to be called to show the value.

> **#pre_render**
>
> **Used by:** All elements and forms.
>
> **Description:** Function(s) to call before rendering in drupal_render()
>   has occured. The function(s) provided in #pre_render receive the
>   element as an argument and must return the altered element.
>
> **Values:** An array of function names to call.
>
> **Note:** If you are altering an existing form via hook_form_alter() or a
>   similar means, be careful with this property! As demonstrated here,
>   you will probably want to add to the existing array rather than
>   writing over it.

I recommend being careful of when your module runs when trying to interact with Forms, Ajax, etc (your modules' weight). If needed I also recommend seeing [hook_module_implements_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7) if you want to adjust when your hook is called, without affecting your modules' weight.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook into the form before processing the $form array not in a template file.  See [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).  Also if you are wanting to make a field output a certain way when that field is rendered you need to look into changing the [field template](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7).

What you are doing is trying to render a form field inside a template which does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in [template_preprocess_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7)

```
function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  if (isset($element['#field_name'])) {
    if ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_machine_name') {
          //do your changes
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the template.php of the appropriate theme, run code similar to the snippet i am giving:

```
function themename_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // dpm($form);
  // Use dpm to see the actual values that you are getting. Based on that change the lines below. Since $form is passed by refernce to this funciton, whatever change you make to the values, will be updated on the tpl file also.
  $old_value = $form['#user']->field_field_name['und'][0]['value'];
  $messaged_value = make_seo_url($old_value);
  $form['#user']->field_field_name['und'][0]['value'] = $messaged_value;
}
```

I think this should help. It uses [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7). To use [`dpm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7), the Devel module needs to be enabled and the logged-in user needs to have the proper permissions to see the debug information.